# Jsch on Ubuntu 12.04 import statement

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to use the jsch package, to test its scp capability inside Java. I tried to install libjsch-java via apt-get to find it was already installed.

When I tried to compile the script on [this page](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpTo.java.html) it said the package does not exist:

ScpTo.java:11: package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist

Am I doing something wrong? It seems the library is installed but perhaps it needs to be called using a different name. How can I find out what name I need to use please? Or is there a different problem I have not considered?

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar file to your classpath. If you are compiling with command line add `-cp path/jsch.jar` to your command line.

If you are working with IDE add the jar using tools it provides.

Comment: I tried as you suggested (I am compiling at command line), and got the same error...

Comment: Please post more details. I guess this is your first java experience. You are trying to do a trivial thing. If it does not work and you are expecting relevant help please give us more details.